# Yolo hangs on video

Tags: object-detection, darknet, yolo

I built the latest version of darknet with Cuda 8 and OpenCV 3.4.0. When I try to run `./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights shortvid.mp4` it loads everything properly and looks like it's starting, but then just hangs after printing the name of the video file.

It isn't doing anything because my GPU/cpu/mem isn't being utilized. Anybody know what could be happening? I don't have any errors to go by.